# Adding multiple torque vectors together to determine resultant torque

Tags: forces, vectors, torque

I am working in a 2D environment, where there are multiple angular forces (torque) applied at an object. The way I calculated 1 torque "application", was by:

```
momentarm(MA) = PointApplication - CenterOfMass
ParallelComponent(PC) = MA * (F · MA / MA · MA)
AngularForce(AF) = Force(F) - PC
Torque = AF * ||MA||
```

And finally

```
AngularAcceleration = Torque / RotInertia
```

I anticipate that I will have to change up the angular acceleration formula, if I want to calculate the angular acceleration from multiple torque vectors.

What approach do I have to take to achieve this?

---

Note that there are no constraints or restrictions around the axis of rotation, and the forces usually aren't symmetrical, but it can happen sometimes.

Comment: Is the axis of rotation fixed by a constraint?

Comment: @CuriousOne No, there are no restrictions or constraints.

Comment: But in 2d, right, so you can avoid the difficulties of the 3d case (which are non-trivial)? In that case you only have to deal with possible translations and the scalar sum of all torques.

Comment: @CuriousOne And how would I find  and use that scalar some in the angular acceleration formula? If you could put that in an answer please.

Comment: If you are dealing with real torques (i.e. all forces come in pairs that attach to the rotating body symmetrically, so there is no translation in addition to the change in rotation), then you can simply add the torques all up. If the forces that are attaching to the body are not symmetric, then there is also a component that causes an acceleration of the center of mass. I don't know which of the two cases you are looking at?

Comment: @CuriousOne In my case, there will be instances where this symmetry would apply, but usually this is not the case. Does the non-symmetrical way also work for the symmetrical one? Because as mentioned earlier, it will usually not be the case.

Comment: Per Newton's second law the vectorial sum of all forces will translate the center of mass. So if your forces don't all add up to zero, then you have to calculate the sum of all torques and integrate twice to get the time dependent angular orientation and you have to use the sum of all forces to get the acceleration of the center of mass and then integrate twice to get the time dependent position.

Comment: @CuriousOne Please put that in an answer, which is quite elaborate as I am not quite advanced in physics, and I believe understanding leads to better education

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant_force

Comment: @CuriousOne Thank you. That's all I need. If you could pu it in an answer please.